# Math.Net error 'Matrix must be positive definite'

Tags: c#, math.net

I attempted to solve a least square question using Cholesky decomposition.

I got an error, 'Matrix must be positive definite'.
I have ensured that the matrix A is column full rank. Besides, I have attempted to output this matrix and I found that it can be calculated by numpy.

I don't know where the problem is.

C# code:

```
var X = A.TransposeThisAndMultiply(A).Cholesky();
```

Matrix A can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yz5N4iDocHfS9YCstEpMvkBpyNrwQu1f/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Considering the nature of the request, I wonder if this question would be more suitable on another StackExchange site, one specific to mathematics? Be sure to read the relevant FAQ before cross-posting.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, MickyD, thank you for your reply. I guess this question is about the math library instead of a mathematic problem. Because the same problem can be computed by python's numpy.

Comment: The reason I ask is that the terminology used in the question is going to limit your audience for a non-math-specific site like SO.  I thought I knew a bit about matrices coming from a 3D background but I don't know what _"Cholesky decomposition; positive definite; column full rank; numpy"_ means.  Perhaps if you explained what values you were expecting to get?

Comment: Is the exception from `TransposeThisAndMultiply` or from `Cholesky`?

Comment: The exception is from Cholesky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decompiled their dll and the exception

`throw new ArgumentException("Matrix must be positive definite.");`

is thrown when any factor in the diagonal is less than 0.0

```
for (int index = 0; index < factor.RowCount; ++index)
            {
                double d = factor.At(index, index);
                if (d <= 0.0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Matrix must be positive definite.");
```

For example - given the following definition

```
        Matrix<double> m = Matrix<double>.Build.Random(3, 3);

        m[0, 0] = 1;
        m[0, 1] = 12;
        m[0, 2] = 0;

        m[1, 0] = 2;
        m[1,1] = 37;
        m[1, 2] = -43;

        m[2, 0] = 3;
        m[2, 1] = -43;
        m[2, 2] = 98;
```

the factor at [0,0] and [1,1] and [2,2] - they all must be positive - otherwise you will encounter that exception

***EDIT***

I have managed to make it work as expected. I believe the issue is the way how you are building the matrix - could be incorrect.

This is my implementation:

```
    {
        FileStream stream = File.Open(@"YOUR_PATH_HERE\A.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        Matrix<double> m = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(352, 252);
        int row = 0;
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            do
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < 252; column++)
                    {
                        var value = reader.GetDouble(column);
                        m[row, column] = value;
                    }
                    row++;
                }
            } while (reader.NextResult());
        }

        excelReader.Close();

        Matrix<double> transpose = m.TransposeThisAndMultiply(m);
        Cholesky<double> p = transpose.Cholesky();
    }
```

[image]

***EDIT 2***

In order to use a Sparse Matrix we could force the values only to go into the Diagonal

**Eg:**

```
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            do
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < 252; column++)
                    {
                        //var value = reader.GetDouble(column);
                        //m[row, column] = value;

                        if (column == row)
                        {
                            var value = reader.GetDouble(column);
                            m[row, column] = value;
                        }
                    }
                    row++;
                }
            } while (reader.NextResult());
        }
```

With the following output:

[image]

*Please note that since the original Sparse Matrix is not square we might have some data loss here.*

Comment: Indeed, positve diagonal elements is a necessary (but not sufficient) criterion for positive definiteness.

Comment: @KlausGütter  -  yes you are right - but this is how the Math.net  guys are handling it in their code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I've checked my matrix ATA. All diagonal elements are positive. Are there any other triggers?

Comment: Set your debug options to break when the exception is thrown, then have a look at the call stack.

Comment: Please consider up-voting and accepting an answer by clicking on that checkmark! if it was helpfull

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Yes, the problem happens on my matrix building. Best wishes!

Comment: I found that using a sparse matrix causes Cholesky's problem. Could you please try to solve it with sparse matrix?

Comment: @AlbertLi That will be correct - A Sparse Matrix will allocate all its data  on a diagonal. My approach meanwhile is using a Dense Matrix in order to accommodate the xlsx file you have provided -  storing on a  row-column basis.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the program above with minor differences that might have affecting rounding and got determinant = 4.9714636E-19. Probably not a big deal, but it suggests that the result is a bit unstable. Not too surprising given the amount of arithmetic involved.